# File output manipulation - ideally in one line

Tags: awk, sed, cut, tr

Apologies in advance this is my first post, hope you can understand it etc.

Original File

```
cat trail
PROC_Create     root     OK          Mon Jun 05 16:05:45 2017 bash                          Global
    forked child process 31522922
PROC_Execute    root     OK          Mon Jun 05 16:05:45 2017 audit                         Global
    euid: 0 egid: 0 epriv: ffffffff:ffffffff name audit shutdown


vi and :set list

PROC_Create     root     OK          Mon Jun 05 16:05:45 2017 bash                          Global                    $
    forked child process 31522922$
PROC_Execute    root     OK          Mon Jun 05 16:05:45 2017 audit                         Global                    $
    euid: 0 egid: 0 epriv: ffffffff:ffffffff name audit shutdown $


cat trail | oc -d
0226220                        G   l   o   b   a   l
0226240                                                               \n
0226260                                    f   o   r   k   e   d       c
0226300    h   i   l   d       p   r   o   c   e   s   s       3   1   5
0226320    2   2   9   2   2  \n   P   R   O   C   _   E   x   e   c   u
0226340    t   e                   r   o   o   t                       O
0226360    K                                           M   o   n       J
0226400    u   n       0   5       1   6   :   0   5   :   4   5       2
0226420    0   1   7       a   u   d   i   t
0226440
0226460                    G   l   o   b   a   l
0226500                                                           \n
0226520                                e   u   i   d   :       0       e
0226540    g   i   d   :       0       e   p   r   i   v   :       f   f
0226560    f   f   f   f   f   f   :   f   f   f   f   f   f   f   f
0226600    n   a   m   e       a   u   d   i   t       s   h   u   t   d
0226620    o   w   n      \n
0226625
```

Desired Output

Ideally using some tools that I can pipe the trail file through such as sed/tr/awk etc.

```
PROC_Create     root     OK          Mon Jun 05 16:05:45 2017 bash                            Global        forked child process 31522922
PROC_Execute    root     OK          Mon Jun 05 16:05:45 2017 audit                           Global        euid: 0 egid: 0 epriv: ffffffff:ffffffff name audit shutdown
```

or

```
PROC_Create     root     OK          Mon Jun 05 16:05:45 2017 bash        forked child process 31522922
PROC_Execute    root     OK          Mon Jun 05 16:05:45 2017 audit       euid: 0 egid: 0 epriv: ffffffff:ffffffff name audit shutdown
```

I have manged to just remove the carriage returns and the word Global, but am struggling to just remove the carriage return and /or Global on the lines with Global in.  Thanks in advance.

I have used the following:

```
sed 's/Global//g'
tr -d '\n'
```

but was hoping to do it all with sed but couldn't get it to work when trying to remove the carriage returns.

Larger sample of file

```
S_PASSWD_READ   root     OK          Mon Jun 05 16:05:37 2017 su                              Global
    audit object read event detected /etc/security/passwd
S_PASSWD_READ   root     OK          Mon Jun 05 16:05:37 2017 su                              Global
    audit object read event detected /etc/security/passwd
FILE_Write      root     OK          Mon Jun 05 16:05:37 2017 su                              Global
    file descriptor = 5 filename =
FILE_Write      root     OK          Mon Jun 05 16:05:37 2017 su                              Global
    file descriptor = 3 filename =
PROC_Execute    root     OK          Mon Jun 05 16:05:37 2017 ksh                             Global
   euid: 0 egid: 0 epriv: ffffffff:ffffffff name -ksh
PROC_Create     root     OK          Mon Jun 05 16:05:37 2017 ksh                             Global
    forked child process 40763616
PROC_Execute    root     OK          Mon Jun 05 16:05:37 2017 termdef                         Global
    euid: 0 egid: 0 epriv: ffffffff:ffffffff name termdef
```

Comment: `remove the carriage returns and the word Global` add that code to question.. it will add to efforts you've made to solve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: Assuming all input consists of 2-line pairs where the second line of a pair is appended to the end of the first line in the pair.

A couple (simplistic) awk examples to get the ball rolling:

```
awk '/^[a-zA-Z]/ {printf $0} /^ / {print $0}' trail
```

-or-

```
awk '/^[[:alpha:]]/ {printf $0} /^[[:space:]]/ {print $0}' trail
```

First search pattern is looking for a line that has a letter (lower- or upper-case) in the first postion; if found, use **printf** to output the entire line but **without** a carriage return at the end.

Second search pattern is looking for a line that as a space in the first position; if found, use **print** to output the entire line **with** a carriage return at the end.

---

Borrowing RavinderSingh13's getline idea to eliminate second search pattern:

```
awk '/^[[:alpha:]]/ {printf $0 ; getline ; print}' trail
```

For each line that starts with a character use **printf** to output entire line **without** a carriage return, read next line, **print** entire line **with** a carriage return at the end.

Answer (score 0):

use `sed` with `:label` and `N` may can help, like:

`cat trail | sed ':label;N;s/Global[ \n]*//;N;b label'`

**Edit1**:

```
cat trail | sed '
:label;
N;
s/Global[ \n]*//;
N;
b label'
```

Comment: cat trail | sed ':label;N;s/Global[ \n]*//;N;b label'
sed: The label :label;N;s/Global[ \n]*//;N;b label is greater than eight characters.
Thanks but not quite working......

Comment: @Neil, you probably have non-GNU sed, this works fine on my computor. try this command on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
awk '/^PROC/{sub(/[[:space:]]+Global/,"");val=$0;getline;sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"");printf("%s\t%s\n",val,$0)}'   Input_file
```

Looking for a line which starts with string PROC, if this is the case then substitute space till string Global with NULL, storing current line's value into val. Then jumping into next line by using getline. Now substituting the initial space from line and then printing the val and current line's value with TAB in between them.

**EDIT1:** changing the code as per OP's request now.

```
awk '!/^[[:space:]]/{sub(/[[:space:]]+Global/,"");val=$0;getline;sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"");printf("%s\t%s\n",val,$0)}'   Input_file
```

Comment: Unfortunately not all lines start with proc, my fault for not putting a enough detail subscription.  The start of each line can be 50+ different strings.  New file sample added to original post.  Please can you take another look.

Comment: Considering that each line will have Global at the end and 2nd line will have space at starting, I have modified my code in EDIT1 section now. If you have more conditions then kindly do let us know on same.